# How to increase distance between bullet points in R Markdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

I'm trying to increase the distance between bullet points in R Markdown unsuccessfully. I've tried `enumitem` and a few other changes with no success.

Here is a workable code:

```
---
title: "Title"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Author"
output: beamer_presentation
---

## Slide 1

- Bullet point 1
- Bullet point 2
```

And you should get this:

[image: slides example]

The idea is to increase the space between *Bullet point 1* and *Bullet point 2*.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For ordinary beamer documents one can increase the space between items with

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\itemize}
  {\def\makelabel}
  {\setlength{\itemsep}{5ex}\def\makelabel}
  {}
  {}
```

rmarkdown uses beamer in a very strange way, but it can be hacked like this:

```
---
title: "Title"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Author"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \renewcommand{\tightlist}{\setlength{\itemsep}{5ex}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
---

## Slide 1

- Bullet point 1
- Bullet point 2
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, didn't work :( I tried to add: ```header-include:
  - \usepackage{xpatch}\xpatchcmd{\itemize}{\def\makelabel}{\setlength{\itemsep}{20ex}\def\makelabel}{}{}```

Comment: @UmbertoMignozzetti Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: Sure @samcarter: https://gist.github.com/2bc8af7ecc3f34cf2b691e9395d65eff.git

Comment: @UmbertoMignozzetti Mmmm, for some reason the header include does not make it into the tex file. I'm not sure why

Comment: I'll try to embed a latex template and see how it goes. But I find a quick fix: just hit an extra enter on the slides (smt like the ` \\ `) on latex. This works fine for my purposes.

Comment: @UmbertoMignozzetti Please have a look at my updated answer